# Почему не работает CORS?

Tags: ajax, yii2, vue.js, cors, axios

Доброго всем дня, наблюдаю очень странное поведение фреймворка Yii2, в частности речь о фильтре **yii\filters\Cors**, он у меня настроен в контроллере от **yii\rest\Controller**, проблема в том - что я со стороны клиента не получаю от сервера указанные в CORS заголовки, ниже код.

**Контроллер AuthController:**

```
use yii\rest\Controller;
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    // remove authentication filter
    $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'];
    unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

    // add CORS filter
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
    ];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

**UrlManager:**

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => \yii\web\UrlManager::class,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'auth' => 'auth/login',
        ],
    ],
```

**Request запрос:**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,bg;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type,http_access_control_allow_credentials,http_access_control_max_age,http_access_control_request_headers,http_origin
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:serverapi.loc
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/63.0.3239.84 Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
```

**Response ответ:**

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 23 Jan 2018 10:29:53 GMT
Server:nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

**Сам запрос выполняю из Vue Axios:**

```
axios.post('http://serverapi.loc/auth', {
      'username': 'login',
      'password': 'pass'
    }, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      }
    })
```

Помогите разобраться, в чем беда?